# Stata: Is there a way to take second and third observations for the same study id and put them all under one?

Tags: stata, data-cleaning

I have a Stata dataset with 3385 unique participants and 6669 respiratory panels (so some participants had 1, 2, 3+ panels). Each panel consists of 34 tests, and these have a value range of 0,1 for a positive or negative result. There are other variables in the dataset that can't be lost, but the IDs, dates of panel, and results are the most important. Currently, my data look like this:

[image]

Is there any way in Stata to take those second and third panels for the same participant, turn them into new variables for the first panel, and clean it all up so it looks like:

[image]

I believe this is called "widening the dataset", but none of the tricks I've found online have been able to work with my specific circumstance. I know it will involve a decent amount of cleaning, but anything has to be better than manually creating a whole new Excel worksheet, which is just subject to too much potential error.

Comment: The command is `reshape wide` and it's a generally a bad idea within Stata. Hundreds of posts on Statalist advise against it,  Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Cross-posted on https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1545651-is-there-a-way-to-take-a-second-and-third-observation-for-the-same-study-id-and-put-them-all-under-one where the same advice is given at greater length. It's courteous to tell people about cross-posting.